# Highlight Data Points in Birt Reports

Tags: birt

creating simple charts with BIRT is easy, but now I would like to bring some more life to them...

imagine a simple line chart. Let's define as a requirement, that the maximum value should be highlighted. A further requirement would be that if the user clicks on this data point, something happens.

How can I solve this?

I can imagine that I could created a second value series which consists only of the highlighted data points.

But it would be nicer if there was a JavaScript API (or even a server side java api) with which I could loop through the data points and add a highlight on the fly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a good starting point:

http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/276-birt-chart-scripting-dynamic-markers-and-datapoint-colors/

Now I have to find a way to add on click events to certain data points...